# Mouse click location on an image

Tags: image, gwt, event-handling

I have a GWT container with some stuff in it and an image which is added a clickhandler.

What I try to do is to get the exact mouse event's X and Y coordinates relative to the image. I saw the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726137/tracking-mouse-movements-over-a-page-with-gwt)
but this is not what I want.

As far as I can see, I have option like getting the image absolute location and event location but this works only if the user doesn't scroll down the page.

```
event.getNativeEvent().getClientY()- image.getElement().getAbsoluteTop();
```

Comment: I don't know much about gwt, but if the above methods exist, there should be a function to get the scrollX and scrollY just like in javascript. Then you would combine all of the above to be event.getNativeEvent().getClientY()-image.getElement().getAbsoluteTop()-(document.scrollTop?)

Comment: yeap, this is the thing I am looking for, and this is the code for it

event.getNativeEvent().getClientY()- image.getAbsoluteTop() + Document.get().getScrollTop()

thanks for the very useful insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Samuel,

here is the solution

```
event.getNativeEvent().getClientY()- image.getAbsoluteTop() + Document.get().getScrollTop()
```