# Click location in image using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there an easy way to find where user clicked inside an image (div, ...), relative to top-left corner of the element? (using js/jquery)

Basic event.pageX/event.pageY does not take into account scrolling and element position. Combining Document.getScrollTop() and element.getAbsoluteTop ( [Mouse click location on an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852921/mouse-click-location-on-an-image) ) does not look nice at all (may not even work on all browsers as far as I know).

Is there a simpler way to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128643/get-accurate-position-for-a-click-on-a-linked-image-using-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems simple enough:

```
$('#yourImg').click(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft,
        y = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;
});
```

[**See demo →**](http://jsfiddle.net/FTHLX/1/)