# window.onkeyup in GWT

Tags: gwt

How do I convert the javascript code "window.onkeyup" (or onkeyup in body tag) to GWT?

Regards

Comment: You might want to edit the title of this question, since it doesn't appear to have anything to do with window.onload

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a page wide listener, you want to take a look at [Event.addNativePreviewHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html#addNativePreviewHandler(com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.NativePreviewHandler)). Attaching a keyup listener there should give you the effect you want. Modifing the snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726137/tracking-mouse-movements-over-a-page-with-gwt) should get you started:

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler() {
  public void onPreviewNativeEvent(final NativePreviewEvent event) {
    final int eventType = event.getTypeInt();
    switch (eventType) {
      case Event.ONKEYUP:
        //magic here
        break;
      default:
        // not interested in other events
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do that with KeyboardListener.

There is a good discussion thread about it (and some issues):
http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/6072c87aa27a2d6e/524334b959683f77

Comment: but that is not for body.onkeyup :(

Comment: also listeners are deprecated in favor of handlers since GWT 1.6